# Problem in instantiating an array of references to an abstract class

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, compiler-errors, abstract-class

I have a program with an `abstract` parent class `Animal`, and three subclasses extended from it.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

abstract class Animal{
    String name, breed, color;
    int age;
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    void bark(){
        System.out.println("Dog:-\nwoof-woof!!!");
    }
}
class Cat extends Animal{
    void meow(){
        System.out.println("Cat-\nmeowww!");
    }
}
class Lion extends Animal{
    void roar(){
        System.out.println("Lion:-\nGgrrrrr!!");
    }
}

class AnimalMain{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Animal a[]= new Animal[3];
        a[0]=new Dog();
        a[1]=new Cat();
        a[2]=new Lion();
        a[0].bark();
        a[1].meow();
        a[2].roar();
    }
}
```

However, I get an error saying the methods `bark()`, `meow()` and `roar()` are not found. i.e:

```
source_file.java:97: error: cannot find symbol

    a[0].bark();

        ^

  symbol:   method bark()

  location: class Animal

source_file.java:98: error: cannot find symbol

    a[1].meow();

        ^

  symbol:   method meow()

  location: class Animal

source_file.java:99: error: cannot find symbol

    a[2].roar();

        ^

  symbol:   method roar()

  location: class Animal

3 errors
```

It seems the objects are still of type `Animal` somehow. How is this possible and how to solve it?

Comment: Those methods only exists in the inheriting classes. You need to cast to your implementations or make a abstract method in th super class

Comment: You define your array as `Animal[]`, so for the compiler it only contains elements of type Animal. `bark`, `roar`, or `meow` methods are not defined by `Animal` (only in its child classes)

Comment: In particular, how would you *expect* this to work? Would you expect `a[2].roar()` to compile, but `a[1].roar()` to cause a compilation failure? It's unrealistic to expect the compiler to "know"  more type information about what's in individual array elements than the array declaration provides.

Comment: Not that you need an array to demonstrate this: `Animal lion = new Lion(); lion.roar();` will show exactly the same error.

Answer (score 7):

The elements of `a` are references to `Animal`. I.e., while they may hold objects of any subclass of `Animal`, in compile-time the compiler is not aware of the exact instance that may happen to be at a specific index, so you're only allowed to use methods that exist in the `Animal` class.

If you're sure you know what instance is at a specific index (e.g., because you placed it there), you can explicitly downcast it and use the methods of that instance, e.g.:

```java
a[0] = new Dog();
((Dog)(a[0])).bark();
```

Having said that, a more idiomatic approach would be to move the declaration to a method in the abstract class:

```java
abstract class Animal{
    String name, breed, color;
    int age;

    abstract void noise();
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    void bark(){
        System.out.println("Dog:-\nwoof-woof!!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void noise() {
        bark();
    }
}
class Cat extends Animal{
    void meow(){
        System.out.println("Cat-\nmeowww!");
    }

    @Override
    public void noise() {
        meow();
    }
}
class Lion extends Animal{
    void roar(){
        System.out.println("Lion:-\nGgrrrrr!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void noise() {
        roar();
    }
}

class AnimalMain{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Animal arr[]= new Animal[3];
        arr[0]=new Dog();
        arr[1]=new Cat();
        arr[2]=new Lion();

        for (Animal a : arr) {
            a.noise();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is that the methods bark(), meow(), and roar() are not defined in the parent class Animal, but you are trying to call them on an array of Animal objects.

Error message gives you a hint about it:

```
source_file.java:97: error: cannot find symbol

    a[0].bark();

        ^

  symbol:   method bark()

  location: class Animal
```

You can read it as follows: You try to call method `bark()` on a reference `a[0]`, the not found symbol (method) is `bark()` and the location (type of reference) is `class Animal`. You should look into class `Animal` to check for not found symbol `bark()`. In your code You will not find it there.

You can only call methods that are part of the objects declared type, not its actual type. To solve this, you can either define these methods in the parent class (as abstract methods if you don't want to provide a default implementation), or you can use downcasting to call these methods. Downcasting is when you cast an object of a superclass to a subclass, this allow you to call subclass specific methods.

Here is an example of how you can use downcasting:

```
((Dog) a[0]).bark();
((Cat) a[1]).meow();
((Lion) a[2]).roar();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that you're trying to call the bark(), meow(), and roar() methods on objects of the Animal class, which is the declared type of your array a. Since these methods are defined in the subclasses (Dog, Cat, and Lion), you need to cast the objects to their respective subclass types in order to call these methods.

```
class AnimalMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Animal a[] = new Animal[3];
        a[0] = new Dog();
        a[1] = new Cat();
        a[2] = new Lion();

        if (a[0] instanceof Dog) {
            ((Dog) a[0]).bark();
        }

        if (a[1] instanceof Cat) {
            ((Cat) a[1]).meow();
        }

        if (a[2] instanceof Lion) {
            ((Lion) a[2]).roar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This could work, but how would you handle the case when there are 10000 different possible subclasses or even the case when you do not know what the subclasses might be?

Comment: Good point, casting each object individually becomes very impractical

Comment: I think this can be solved if you have an abstract method and the subclasses are to implement it. Then you can be sure that `bark` and `meow` will appropriately be called. Nevertheless, I upvote your answer, because it contains a useful idea.